# A non-function __get__ attribute of a descriptor receives an additional argument when called, why?

Tags: python

Can someone explain why a non-function `__get__` attribute of a descriptor seems to receive an additional argument when called - namely the descriptor object (which is implicitly passed as self in the case of a function)?

In the example below both `B` and `C` are non-data descriptors (they have an `__get__` attribute). `B`'s `__get__` attribute is an instance of `A` - which is callable - and `C`'s is an instance of function (a function) - also callable. Classes `D` and `E` have an attribute called `attr` which is of type `B` and `C` respectively.

From my understanding of python's attribute lookup process, accessing the `attr` attribute of an instance of `D/E` will ultimately find `attr` in `D/E.__dict__` and registering it is non-data descriptor will return the result of calling `__get__` on the descriptor object - however the signature of this call appears to be different depending on the type of the descriptors `__get__` attribute.

I don't have a specific use-case for this scenario but imagining that `A` is acting as a kind of state-ful function class I can see how this behaviour makes sense from a design perspective as a way for `A` to communicate back to the descriptor. I cannot however understand *why* this behaviour happens - is this behaviour implicit or am I missing something?

```
class A(object):
    def __call__(self, desc, obj, cls):
        print 'A::__call__\n'

class B(object):
    __get__ = A()

class C(object):
    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        print 'C::__get__\n'

class D(object):
    attr = B()

class E(object):
    attr = C()

>>> D().attr
A::__call__
>>> E().attr
C::__get__
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `__get__`. You'll see the same effect without involving descriptors:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __call__(self, arg):
...         return arg
...
>>> a = A()
>>> def b(arg):
...     return arg
...
>>> a(3)
3
>>> b(3)
3
```

The thing is that `A.__call__` is an unbound method, while a function's signature, being specific to that particular instance of the function type, is more analogous to the signature of a bound method.

Rather than comparing `A.__call__`'s signature to that of an individual function, you should compare the signature of an `A` instance to that of a function. As demonstrated above, the signature of the instance and the function exactly match. Alternatively, you could compare `A.__call__` to `types.FunctionType.__call__`, which does take the function instance as its first argument:

```
>>> import types
>>> types.FunctionType.__call__(b, 3)
3
```